# Jest: How to load file stub?

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I have an image file I need to use in my tests. I need to pass this `File` object around and call certain methods on it.

```
const readTestFile = () =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(testFilePath, (err, data) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      const blob = new File(data, "file.png"); // <-------- doesn't work in NodeJS
      return resolve(blob);
    });
  });
```

How would I load it the "jest" way? Also I need a `File` object (not a string), how would I get around this?

Comment: Did you actually have problems with `new File`? Jest uses JSDOM by default that provides `File`.

Comment: yeh. i think it is because i ejected react, so i'm missing something...

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this by changing:

```
testEnvironment: "node"
```

to

```
testEnvironment: "jsdom"
```